# i am getting error(on postman api call) Error: Request failed with status code 401

Tags: reactjs, postman

> i have get 401 error on Postman api calling TOKEN and api is right and also api call successfully in POSTMAN

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get('http://192.168.10.0:9000/getquestions', {
      params: {
        token: 'MYTOKEN'
        ,headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("res"+res)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log("error"+e))
  }
```

Comment: It says you are unauthorized (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), so you need to figure out what's the authentication scheme and send correct information to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing token as string you should change it, as I guess MYTOKEN is variable with long token